# Theos did not specify a target error

Tags: ios, makefile, jailbreak, theos

Trying to build a tweak using theos and having this error

```
/var/theos/makefiles/common.mk:103: *** You did not specify a target, and the "i          phone" platform does not define a default target.  Stop.
```

My Makefile is as shown

```
ARCHS = armv7 armv7s
SDKVERSION = 7.0
TARGET = iphone:7.0

include /var/theos/makefiles/common.mk

BUNDLE_NAME = sometweak
bustiming_FILES = Toggle.xm
bustiming_INSTALL_PATH = /Library/Application Support/CCToggles/Toggles

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/bundle.mk
```

Not sure what am I missing out, I've searched multiple websites and they said it's because of the missing TARGET in the Makefile however it's not working. Any advise is appreciated thanks.

Comment: I take it you are a beginner with Make. Who wrote these files?

Comment: I got it from https://github.com/coolstar/theos

Comment: It looks as if you're supposed to invoke Make with a target name argument, like "make iphone" or "make tweak". Anyway, you should look over the theos documentation, because there's no way we can guess the target name from this.

Comment: but I read the documentation and it says the default target name is iphone. anyway thanks for your help

Comment: You could try "make iphone", but it really looks as if this build system does *not* have a default target.

Comment: I tried "make iphone" but still it gives the same error.

Comment: *The same* error? That you didn't specify a target? That's very strange.

Comment: yes same error, I'm not sure whether I can just change the common.mk file to include iphone in it

Comment: Try reinstalling theos and recreating the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/ instead of /var/theos/

Also try listing your Target as TARGET = iphone:latest:7.0

Finally, make sure before you use build, you have set the environment variables :-

```
export THEOS=/opt/theos
export THEOS_DEVICE_IP=192.168.0.2  (your phone ip)
export SKDVERVSION=7.0  (or whatever you are building for)
```